# Post notification from OBJC to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, notifications

I have an app with objc code, and today extension using swift code.
How can I send data from objc to swift. This is my code, and it doesn't work:

OBJC:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"todayExtensionData" object:myData];
```

Swift:

```
...
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateData(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name("todayExtensionData"), object: nil)
...

@objc func updateData(notification: Notification){
    print(notification)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You app and today extension are run as separate processes on the phone. NSNotificationCenter only works within a single process.

To pass information between your extension and main app, you can use NSUserDefaults or a file in the shared container.

NOTE: If you use above code in same app, it will work perfect.

Comment: Thank you. Just a note - you need to enable App Groups capability, then use Shared User Defaults. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/shared-user-defaults-in-ios-3f15cd2c9409